# How to schedule intervals and start at certain date and time with Azure CRON Expression

Tags: azure, cron, scheduled-tasks

We need to produce Azure CRON Expression to start job at certain date between a start and end time at intervals of hours or minutes.

So say if I want the job to run every 30 mins starting from 7:30 AM to 1:30 PM everyday, my expression should go like below?

```
0 30/30 7-13 * * *
```

And to run every 2 hours starting from 7:30 AM to 1:30 PM everyday, my my expression should go like below?

```
0 30 7-13/2 * * *
```

Is it possible to achieve these with Azure CRON at all? If not what's my alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CRON Expressions are not `Azure` specific but `CRON` specific.

First you need to get deep into the [cron and understand how it works and what does the cron expression mean here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression). Then you can use tools like [CRONTab Guru here](http://crontab.guru/#20,50_7-13_*_*_*) to get to your expression.

To get to something that might be the one you search for:

> 0,30 7-13 * * *

This expression is read:

> “At minute 0 and 30 past every hour from 7 through 13.”

Which is basically every 30 minutes starting at 07:00 and ending at 13:30.

You can give yourself a try with the CronTab Guru and find the best suiting formula for you.